# Form Validation in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m trying to add validation to my form components in React.

What I've got is my form contained within a react component with each individual form item as a separate react component.

Now I need to add validation and taking a hint from [formsy](https://github.com/formsy/formsy-react/) how to structure this but I'm curious if anyone has a better option rather than writing my own validation from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Redux-Forms](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form).

Redux-form works with React Redux to enable an html form in React to use Redux to store all of its state.

Comment: thanks, i was looking at redux-forms but my app still uses flux, might be able to shoehorn it in